# Altering the variable of integration

Tags: integration, differential

I've got a book (*Power Electronics: Converters, Applications, and Design*, Mohan, 2003) which gives the following equation:

$$L_s \frac{di_u}{dt} = \frac{{v_a}_n - {v_c}_n}{2} $$

It then goes on to say we multiply both sides by $\omega$ (rad/sec) and integrate, giving

$$\omega L_s \int_0^{I_d} di_u=\int_0^u \frac{{v_a}_n - {v_c}_n}{2} d(\omega t)$$

What I can't figure out is, after multiplying by $\omega$ on the right-hand side, why does $\omega$ get incorporated into the variable of integration? The variable was $dt$, and now we're saying it's $d(\omega t)$. Am I missing some mathematical property that would allow this?

Comment: Looks like a somehat less-than-rigorous notation for a change of variable $\omega t \to w$ that avoids introducing a new symbol.

Comment: So, like saying "$\omega t = t$" and then "$dt = d(\omega t)$"?

Comment: Because $\omega dt=d(\omega t)$.

Comment: That’s the idea, although you should avoid reusing variables when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I see what is happening, assuming $\omega$ is constant.  Let me walk through the steps and see if it looks right.  I am going to use $\omega = \frac{dr}{dt}$ (where $r$ is radians). This also means that $dr = \omega\,dt$.

Therefore:
$$
L_s \frac{di_u}{dt} = \frac{{v_a}_n - {v_c}_n}{2} ~~\text{(starting equation)} \\
dr\,L_s \frac{di_u}{dt} = \frac{{v_a}_n - {v_c}_n}{2}\,dr ~~\text{(multiply both sides by $dr$)} \\
\frac{dr}{dt} L_s\, di_u = \frac{{v_a}_n - {v_c}_n}{2}\,dr ~~\text{(rearrange)} \\
\omega\, L_s\, di_u = \frac{{v_a}_n - {v_c}_n}{2}\omega\,dt ~~\text{(substitute)} \\
\omega\, L_s\, di_u = \frac{{v_a}_n - {v_c}_n}{2}d(\omega\,t) ~~\text{(constant multiplier rule)} \\
\int \omega\, L_s\, di_u = \int \frac{{v_a}_n - {v_c}_n}{2}d(\omega\,t) ~~\text{(integrate both sides)} \\
\omega\, L_s \int di_u = \int \frac{{v_a}_n - {v_c}_n}{2}d(\omega\,t) ~~\text{(constant rule)}
$$